# How do I do a wildcard search inside Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: gui, azure

I'm trying to do a search for `*40075*` inside azure folder search box, and was wondering how I can do a real wildcard search from the folder search box, and how.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, you can't.  The "search" box is a prefix (starts-with) filter only.

Comment: And the long answer please?

Comment: I guess the reason is because this type of search has better performance and less load for their servers.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't completely answer your question but it may help some folks including yourself.  The **[Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/)** desktop application enables a little bit more flexibility, but NOT MUCH.  Overall, this is disappointing and inconvenient.  Doing a wildcard search is a pretty basic file explorer feature and Azure Storage is failing us by not allowing it.  This is now 5 years after your post and we still can't do it.